# How to create a HTTPS server that listens on my IP address

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express, https

In Python Flask, I tried creating an ad hoc and OpenSSL based certificate as shared in https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https

I also tried the approach where we create root CA, trust it and create certificates as shared in https://github.com/dakshshah96/local-cert-generator/issues/13 with Python Flask and Express JS

But I am unable to talk to https://192.168.0.5:5000 hosted on my Mac, from a different device without manually approving the site on every load. Ultimately, I wish to talk to this server over a web socket, which fails as the site requires manual approval. Any other ideas on how to make this multi-system setup work?

Comment: Use [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) rather than generating your own certificate?

Comment: Does the device you are using to reach the express server has the certificate in his trusted store?

Comment: in your first link you have `Using "Real" Certificates` which shows how to use `Let's Encrypt`. And `Let's Encrypt` creates trusted cert for free.

Comment: @sqz and furas, thanks for your ideas. My understanding is that it needs a public domain to issue a certificate. For localhost their ideas do not work for my case https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Comment: @Atomzwieback, I'm trying to reach the express server from Chrome / Safari on an iPhone. How can I add it to the trusted store, so that it does not ask for any future visits?

Comment: @Nitin this explains it: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123988/how-to-add-a-crt-certificate-to-iphones-keychain

Answer (score 1):

The example which I am going to deliver will run your application in the local network and it will be accessible using your computer (server) IP address over HTTPS.

You need to install OpenSSL to generate a self-signed certificate.

Create a project folder.

Open CMD and navigate to your project folder.

Run the following command on CMD

`openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert`

It will ask you some questions, answer them.

In your project folder, create app.js file and insert the following code:

```
let express = require('express')
let fs = require('fs')
let https = require('https')
let app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app)
.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000! Go to https://localhost:3000/')
})
```

Find your local IP address using `ipconfig` command. Your IP address will appear something like

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.124
```

Run your NodeJs server by using the command:

`node app.js`

You will get the following message:

`Example app listening on port 3000! Go to https://localhost:3000/`

Go to the browser and visit `https://your_ip:3000/`;

You will get a warning, ignore it. This is to alert that the certificate which you are using is a self-signed certificate and not issued by CA.

You can use the link to visit your application from any other device on your network. If you are tired of port 3000, you can use port 443 which is the default port for HTTPS. In that case, your URL will be simplified to something like `https://your_ip/`

I have verified through Wireshark that data is encrypted now!!

To answer this question, I took help from https://flaviocopes.com/express-https-self-signed-certificate/

Comment: Thank you for your detailed post Aqib. I get `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID` on Chrome 84 for both localhost and my IP address. Eventually I wish to connect to this server via sockets which will fail for any type of cert warnings as well, was my understanding